# How To Set Browser Cookies With Curl

Tags: php

I have a curl function as shown below. To load this function i use this `<img src="http://site.com/pxl.php?i=1.jpg" height="1" width="1" />` but when i do that cookies dont get added to my browser. Is there a way so that when the curl run on the url i collect the cookies from the url and set it to the browser of using accessing `<img src="http://site.com/pxl.php?i=1.jpg" height="1" width="1" />`

```
function get_content($url,$ref)
{
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$ch = curl_init();

$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browser);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
return $html;
}
```

Comment: isnt it that browser and curl work in different process space. So how come cookie set by the curl will become visible to browser?

Comment: well the same thing can be said about the referrer and useragent but thats changeable

Comment: referrer and user agent dont store anything on disk where as cookie is stored on the disk.

Answer (score -1):

To send a cookie to a page using cURL, Use the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'user=alice; activity=knitting');
```

To set cookies for the script, use [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);
```

Comment: Ok so how do i collect original cookies from $url ? What i want to do is collect cookies from that url and then set it to the browser